# Openlayer2 : what is JSTS library Buffer length unit?

Tags: openlayers

I am using

> ```
> var buffer = input.buffer(100);
> ```
>
> But What is its measurement unit ? is 100 in meter or kilometers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the `buffer` units are based on the map projection.  So, in the example below which is `EPSG:3857` the units are in meters.

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/jsts.html

```
// convert the OpenLayers geometry to a JSTS geometry
var jstsGeom = parser.read(feature.getGeometry());

// create a buffer of 40 meters around each line
var buffered = jstsGeom.buffer(40);
```

If the map projection was `EPSG:4326` then it would be degrees.

See this doc for openlayers 2 http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.map and view `projection` and `units`.

Comment: Yes My guess was aswell that. Thank you btw

Comment: So if I want to take input in Miles then I will multiply it with 1609.34?

Comment: Yep, (Miles * 1609.34 = Meters to use when calling `buffer`).  Good luck with your project..

Comment: Thank you brother.